# qt openGL support on linux

Tags: linux, qt, qt4

i wan't to know if i have opeGL support on my linux, and i don't know how to do that.
i need to run a qt application written with openGL, but the CPU consumption is very high...

what can i check, and how exactly?

this is  the output for glxinfo:

```
----------------------------------
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_hyperpipe, 
    GLX_SGIX_swap_barrier, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa Project
OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.9-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_program, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_imaging, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, 
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_shadow_ambient, 
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_compression, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ARB_window_pos, 
    GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_logic_op, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, 
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_convolution, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
    GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_histogram, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_paletted_texture, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_shared_texture_palette, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, 
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, 
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, 
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, 
    GL_ATI_fragment_shader, GL_ATI_separate_stencil, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_resize_buffers, GL_MESA_texture_array, 
    GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_blend_square, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fragment_program, 
    GL_NV_fragment_program_option, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_point_sprite, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, 
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vertex_program, 
    GL_NV_vertex_program1_1, GL_OES_read_format, GL_SGI_color_matrix, 
    GL_SGI_color_table, GL_SGI_texture_color_table, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

64 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x021 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c3 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c4 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0c5 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c6 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0c7 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c8 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0c9 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ca 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0cb 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0cc 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0cd 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ce 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0cf 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d0 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0d1 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d2 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0d3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0d5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0d7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0d9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0da 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0db 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0dc 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0dd 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0de 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0df 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0e0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0e1 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e2 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0e3 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e4 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0e5 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e6 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0e7 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e8 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0e9 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ea 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0eb 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ec 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ed 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ee 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ef 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0f1 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f2 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0f3 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f4 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0f5 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f6 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0f7 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f8 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0f9 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0fa 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0fb 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0fc 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0fd 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0fe 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0ff 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x100 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x042 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

128 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x043  0 tc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x044  0 tc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x045  0 tc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x046  0 tc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x047  0 tc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x048  0 tc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x049  0 tc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x04a  0 tc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x04b  0 tc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x04c  0 tc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x04d  0 tc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x04e  0 tc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x04f  0 tc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x050  0 tc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x051  0 tc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x052  0 tc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x053  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x054  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x055  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x056  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x057  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x058  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x059  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x05a  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x05b  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x05c  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x05d  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x05e  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x05f  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x060  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x061  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x062  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x063 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x064 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x065 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x066 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x067 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x068 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x069 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x06b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x06d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06e 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x06f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x070 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x071 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x072 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x073 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x074 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x075 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x077 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x078 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x079 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x07b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x07d 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x07f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x080 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x081 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x082 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x083  0 dc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x084  0 dc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x085  0 dc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x086  0 dc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x087  0 dc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x088  0 dc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x089  0 dc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08a  0 dc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x08b  0 dc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08c  0 dc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x08d  0 dc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08e  0 dc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x08f  0 dc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x090  0 dc  0   8  0 r  . .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x091  0 dc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x092  0 dc  0   8  0 r  y .   3  3  2  0 .  .  0  8  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x093  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x094  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x095  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x096  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x097  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x098  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x099  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09a  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x09b  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09c  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x09d  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09e  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x09f  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a0  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a1  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a2  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a3 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a4 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a5 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a6 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a7 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a8 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a9 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0aa 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ab 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ac 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ad 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ae 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0af 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b1 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b2 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b3 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b4 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0b5 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b6 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0b7 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b8 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0b9 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ba 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0bb 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bc 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0bd 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0be 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0bf 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c0 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0c1 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c2 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
```

**lspci output:**

```
--------------
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX AGP bridge (rev 01)
00:07.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA (rev 08)
00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:07.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:07.7 System peripheral: VMware Virtual Machine Communication Interface (rev 10)
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
00:10.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev 01)
00:11.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI bridge (rev 02)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
02:00.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 USB
02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] (rev 10)
02:02.0 Multimedia audio controller: Ensoniq ES1371 [AudioPCI-97] (rev 02)
02:03.0 USB Controller: VMware USB2 EHCI Controller
```

Answer (score 2):

```
direct rendering: Yes
```

Direct rendering means the application bypasses the XServer to display its thing on the screen. It is not synonymous with hardware acceleration, as the computation can still be done by the application in software form before being displayed.

```
OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer
```

Software rasterizer means your OpenGL is **not** hardware accelerated, and the mesa driver has to compute everything on the CPU before it can render it directly on the screen. Therefore, an OpenGL application will be slow on such a system as the CPU will do most of the number crunching, as opposed to the GPU.

A hardware accelerated setup will display the name of the video card driver's renderer. Here are 2 examples of strings you should expect to see if your setup supports hardware acceleration :

ATI radeon :

```
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon 3000 Graphics
```

Intel :

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 915G GEM 20091221 2009Q4 x86/MMX/SSE2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use glxinfo utility from mesa-utils package (actual name of a package depends on particular GNU/Linux distribution you use)

`glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"`

If it say Yes, then OpenGL is hardware accelerated.

You should also check if QGLFormat::directRendering() is set to true, which is default value.

Comment: Direct rendering only means the rendering is handled by the application as opposed the the X server. It does not mean it is hardware accelerated, you need to check the renderer string for that.

Answer (score 0):

Download (or install using your package manager of choice) [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and run `glewinfo` which will say something like:

```
OpenGL version 3.3.0 NVIDIA 260.19.36 is supported
```

Comment: info | grep "direct rendering" - output: direct rendering:Yes glewinfo - output: GLEW version 1.5.2 Reporting capabilities of display :0.0, visual 0xc5 Running on a Software Rasterizer from Mesa Project OpenGL version 2.1 Mesa 7.9-devel is supported when i try to run the qt demos for openGL they are very slow....